# Confirm order redirects to login page and destroys session for paypal pro

Tags: php, e-commerce, paypal, oscommerce

I have downloaded paypal pro module and installed it on my OsCommerce v2.2RC2 Installation.
 I have configured this module with API values in admin panel.

Now when user selects "Credit or Debit Card" as payment method which is paypal pro method actually. On Confirm order page it shows a form to get credit/debit card information. But when user clicks on "confirm order", he is redirected to login page and his session is destroyed.

Here is video screen cast of issue.
http://screenr.com/E5zs

Can you suggest some solution?

Thanks,
 Salman

Comment: what should be the process..where user should go once payment is done?

Answer (score 0):

At first the browser is on the "bestremywigs.com" domain, later on you move to "www.bestremywigs.com". Please make sure either you use the same domain throughout or the session/cookies are set with the domain parameter as ".bestremywigs.com", so that it is valid on both "www.bestremywigs.com" and "bestremywigs.com". I think if you do this, the issue will be resolved.